# How can I call JavaScript function in a loop

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I would like to call JavaScript function many time . I have tried like that
    In Script

```
 function changeIt(strgr , idx) {
    //SomeCode
    return;  
 }
```

In C#

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
      string strgr = 001;
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++)  
      {  
          base.RunScriptBottom("changeIt(" + strgr + "," + i + ");");  
      }
 }
```

But it call the script function only one time.
What could I do.
With regards

Comment: What JavaScript does this C# code actually emit to the page?  C# code doesn't "call JavaScript" in the way you might be thinking.  It just builds strings to emit to the page for the browser to interpret.

Comment: You can not call Javascript from C# code. C# code runs on the server, while JAvascript code runs in the client browser. You can only generate javascript code from C# code. In the generated code you can call the javascript function many times if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

By the way, you can write a js function to loop and call from server side once..

```
 function changeAll(strgr , from, to) {

   for(int i = from, i< to; i++)
      changeIt(strgr ,i);
 }
```

Server Side:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
      string strgr = 001;

          base.RunScriptBottom("changeAll(" + strgr + ",0,3);");  

 }
```

Comment: Do not forget that you may need to run javascript functions with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` if you have an `UpdatePanel` on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a client event to do this

```
<asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" OnClientClick="loop()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loop() {
        var strgr = 001;
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++)  
        {  
            changeIt(strgr + "," + i );  
        }
    }
</script>
```